# No Audio in Arch Linux (xmonad)

Tags: arch-linux, alsa, pulseaudio, vlc, xmonad

I am using Arch Linux with xmonad Window Manager. I have installed `alsa-utils`  and As per my knowledge , alsa drivers should installed by default.

But when I try open any media file with cvlc, I get this error :

```
┌─(severus)──(~) 
└─> $ cvlc /run/media/severus/Entertainment/Barton\ Springs\ -\ Bird\ Creek-qIKD169VDy0.opus 
VLC media player 2.2.4 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.3-37-g888b7e89)
[0000000001624e78] pulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused
[000000000166cf38] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1041:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
[0000000001624e78] alsa audio output error: cannot open ALSA device "default": No such file or directory
[0000000001624e78] core audio output error: Audio output failed
[0000000001624e78] core audio output error: The audio device "default" could not be used:
No such file or directory.
[0000000001624e78] core audio output error: module not functional
[00007f3318c0ebe8] core decoder error: failed to create audio output
[00007f3318c0ebe8] opus decoder error: Oops: No new buffer was returned!
^C
┌─(severus)──(~) 
└─> $
```

Output of `alsamixer` :

[image]

[image]

Output of `lspci -k|  grep -A 3 -i audio`:

```
┌─(severus)──(~) 
└─> $ lspci -k|  grep -A 3 -i audio
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2212
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2212
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
┌─(severus)──(~) 
└─> $
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was , Out put was directed to wrong device (HDMI),

I detected this by doing :

`speaker-test -D default:PCH -c 8`

So I created a file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

with the following contents

```
options snd_hda_codec_realtek=0
options snd_hda_intel index=1
```

Everything works like charm :D

More information : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture#Set_the_default_sound_card